# Django: Dynamic jquery form not working when {% csrf_token %} is added

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

I am using a dynamic form in my django template using jquery but when I add submit button or csrf token to the form the dynamic form stops working and I can not add new fields anymore.

Here is my html file

```html
<html>
<body>

  <form method="post">

    <p>
      <label>Name:</label> <input type="text">
      <label>Number:</label> <input type="number">
      <span class="remove">Remove</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </p>

  </form>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".add").click(function() {
      $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
      return false;
    });

    $(".remove").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I insert `{% csrf_token %}` or `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` the dynamic form is not working

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<p>
    <label>Name:</label> <input type="text">
    <label>Number:</label> <input type="number">
    <span class="remove">Remove</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span class="add">Add fields</span>
</p>

</form>
```

,

```html
<form method="post">
    
    <p>
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text">
        <label>Number:</label> <input type="number">
        <span class="remove">Remove</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    

    $(".add").click(function() {
    $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
        return false;
    });

    $(".remove").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });


</script>
```

The form can no more insert/add new fields after this addition. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are as follows:

1. `"form > p:first-child"`: This will give you a `p` tag which is the **first** child of its parent, when you put the `{% csrf_token %}` before the `p` tag it is no longer the first child of the `form` tag.
2. `"form > p:last-child"`: This will give you a `p` tag which is the **last** child of its parent when you add the submit button, there is no p tag which is the last child of the `form` tag.

You can fix this by using `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` selectors, although this is not a very great solution and can easily break if you add other `p` tags. Also your solution can easily break if there are multiple form tags, etc.:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text">
        <label>Number:</label> <input type="number">
        <span class="remove">Remove</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("form > p:first-of-type").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-of-type");
        return false;
    });

    $(".remove").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```